# x-amz-content-sha256 must be UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD, or a valid sha256 value

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman

I am trying to send an image to an aws backend via a multi-form aws4 request. I am using postman. Below is the error output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>x-amz-content-sha256 must be UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD, STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD, or a valid sha256 value.</Message>
    <ArgumentName>x-amz-content-sha256</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>7D78494C962E781C</RequestId>
    <HostId>RLuxhuFW89Qfyspp8BCX4IaoQRqAx8yCk7OTeprRwlqH5OurASuqPNU7WbFcZPItXPcHk/8XBgw=</HostId>
  </Error>
```

Below is the `SubmitTo` data I got

```
"submitTo": {
        "url": "https://optelos-quadro.s3.amazonaws.com",
        "method": "POST",
        "contentType": "multipart/form-data",
        "formData": {
            "key": "Redacted",
            "content-type": "image/jpeg",
            "content-disposition": "inline; filename=file1.JPG",
            "x-amz-credential": "Redacted/20181015/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request",
            "x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
            "x-amz-date": "20181015T000000Z",
            "policy": "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",
            "x-amz-signature": "Redacted"
        }
    },
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: For `POST` requests, `x-amz-content-sha256` goes in the form, not the headers.

Comment: I have the same issue. @Andrew Hoofnagle you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use put instead of post in postman and add the name of the file to the end of the url like /foo.txt and the region after the s3. and before the .amazonaws.com
also remove the region in the Authorization

example: https://test.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test.csv

check the below link for details
https://christinavhastenrath.medium.com/testing-file-uploads-to-aws-s3-with-iam-user-credentials-in-postman-5026fbde3ca6

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with the Postman app itself, I just sent http request to AWS with Node and x-amz-content-sha256 header seem to work.

And since this answer is too simple and short, I'll add working JS code here:

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'
import FormData from 'form-data'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

async function postToAWS() {
  const blob = fs.readFile('test.jpeg')
  const filename = 'test.jpeg'
  const bodyForm = new FormData()
  bodyForm.append('file', blob, filename)

  const response = await fetch('https://reddit-uploaded-media.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: bodyForm,
    headers: {
      'x-amz-content-sha256': ''
    }
  })
}
```